# How to add or remove a record in database based on user login/logout, I am using Devise gem for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, devise

I have certain user settings which I need to load when user logs in & destroy his custom settings after he logs out. I am using Devise gem. Also I intend to keep this settings record id in Rails session for easy access through out the application.

when the user logs out, I want to do something like this:

```
Setting.delete(session[:settings_id])
```

where Setting is my Model class, and I am holding the currently loaded settings_id in session as 
    session[:settings_id] = Settings.where(:conditions => hash).id

then when the user logs out, I will have to delete the record from my settings table using

```
    Setting.delete(session[:settings_id]),
```

since I already have currently loaded settings_id kept in session. How can I do it alongside Devise ?

Comment: Is that it? Share more information as to how you are storing these settings and what you have done so far.

Comment: explanation added, kindly let me know if you need any more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise is build upon warden which provides some [callbacks](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Callbacks) you may use:

```
Warden::Manager.before_logout do |user, auth, opts|
  Setting.delete(auth.session[:settings_id])
end
```

Comment: should I add this in application_controller.rb ?

Comment: No, in a initializer, something like config/inializers/devise.rb. Bare in mind that I haven't tested this code, but I did implement my own callbacks similarly.

Comment: the session here I have mentioned is rails session, so do I still need auth.session[:settings_id] ? or just session[:settings_id] is sufficient

Comment: I think you still need it. Nevertheless, you'll have to test it out your self.

Comment: one question, are you sure session is available to devise.rb ? because if I hardcode ids instead of auth.session[:settings_id] then everything works the way I want, otherwise it doesn't

Comment: @Raul could you please your work if it not confidential ? I want to work on similar thing. I want to add logout time entry in database table for user.